# Sorting not working

Tags: excel, vba

In this user form

[image]

I have the following code (Ascending is by default TRUE, while Descending is False)

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
Dim rRange As Range
lastRow = Sheets("overview").Range("G1000").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a cell in the column you want 
_to sort", Title:="SPECIFY COLUMN", Type:=8)
Col = rRange.Columns(1).Column
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If rRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    If AscendingOption Then
        Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If
    If DescendingOption Then
        Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending        
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When I click OK nothing happens: not an error message, nor any action.
Can anybody help me finding the error?

Comment: What about `AscendingOption` and `DescendingOption`?

Comment: As far as I know `AscendingOption` and `DescendingOption` are not pre-defined so if you don't define them within your `Sub` they will always be `False`.

Comment: You will probably need to set `AscendingOption` and `DescendingOption` to global variables. As Tom mentioned these variables have not been defined in this `Sub`. If you want to test this add the line `Option Explicit` to the beginning of your code. You should get an error when you run the program again.

Comment: Can you give an example? Looking at other sorting examples here I saw the very same code

Comment: Step 1 in finding an error: get rid of `On Error Resume Next` (which might as well be called (`On Error Hide Bug`). There is almost never a valid reason to use that.

Comment: @JohnColeman, this is funny: commenting `'On Error Resume Next` makes the code work, with no error popping up. If yours was an answer I would acknowledge it.

Comment: To me that doesn't make sense. `On Error Resume Next` shouldn't *cause* a bug. Something else must be going on.

Comment: It puzzles me too

Comment: You really should add `Option Explicit` to the top of all your modules. Failing to do that is a notorious source of difficult to track down bugs. What is the point of the `DisplayAlerts` code? An input box shouldn't trigger any alerts. Do you have e.g. a `Selection_Change()` event handler? If so, perhaps you need to turn off event handling rather than alerts (`Application.EnableEvents = False`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the version of the code which works fine:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
Dim rRange As Range
lastRow = Sheets("overview").Range("G1000").End(xlUp).Row
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a cell in the column 
_you want to sort", Title:="SPECIFY COLUMN", Type:=8)
Col = rRange.Columns(1).Column
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If rRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    If AscendingOption Then
        Range("A14:CE" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(14, Col), Cells(lastRow, Col)), 
        _Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), 
        _Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If
    If DescendingOption Then
        Range("A14:CE" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(14, Col), Cells(lastRow, Col)), 
        _Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), 
        _Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If
Unload UserForm1
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Both variables `AscendingOption` and `DescendingOption` are not initialized so are set as `false`. You need to change value of one of them into TRUE to sort. But in current code if both are TRUE, you will sort it twice - firstly ascending and secondly descending. You can reduce code by one variable into:

```
    If AscendingOption Then
        Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    Else
        Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14", Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlDescending, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending
    End If
```

If AscendingOption is true, it sorts in in ascending order, otherwise descending.

Comment: My apologize, I forgot to mention AscendingOption is by default True, while the other is False (see edit)

Comment: Can you print the value of `AscendingOption`, via `debug.print AscendingOption` into Immediate window or via `msgbox AscendingOption`? Because the rest I checked should work fine. Because maybe the value is not provided from userform into code?